# How to change the default infra container in Podman?

Tags: podman

I am trying to use podman-compose to spin up an environment. The env is air gapped from the internet and uses a local docker registry to pull images.

The issue is when I run podman-compose up, it tries to create the initial infra container from the default image "k8s.gcr.io/pause" which is located on the internet.

I have pushed this image to our local registry, but I can't find how to tell podman to use this image instead of the internet one.

Comment: I was able to get around this by creating the infr container manually "podman pod create --name=<name of infra used by containers> --share net --infra --infra-image company-registry.com/k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.5", but hoping there is a default value somewhere as this still throws an ignorable error.

Answer (score 1):

change line "infra_image" in file containers.conf

Container engines will read containers.conf files in up to three
locations in the following order:

1. /usr/share/containers/containers.conf
2. /etc/containers/containers.conf
3. $HOME/.config/containers/containers.conf (Rootless containers ONLY)